# How do we customize tsung scripts for sending message in Openfire server?

Tags: erlang, openfire, tsung

Tsung snippet:

```
<transaction name="sendmessage">
<request> <jabber type="chat" ack="no_ack" size="56" destination="online" /> </request>
</transaction>
```

It Generates below request,

```
<message id='4777' to='testserver270@domain.com' type='chat'>
    <body>qxvmvtglimieyhemzlxcqxvmvtglimieyhemzlxcvtglimieyhemzlxc</body>
</message>
```

How do i customize the tsung scripts to get below request,

```
<message id='395' to='testserver4@dmain.com' type='chat'>
    <msgid>a8aa6f8f-f162-4f1f-b9a0-834180c26fe0</msgid>      
    <sessionkey></sessionkey>      
    <creationtime>1432204640009</creationtime>      
    <senttime>1432204640009</senttime>
    <msgtype>9001</msgtype>      
    <body>02A8E47665F91C415B2E732E105E1FA68E01AF2EA9D03AE8374343A68683</body>      
    <thread>yyMz65</thread>
</message>
```

I have tried using data in jabber tag and passed my custom tag init, and got below request.

```
<message id='395' to='testserver4@chat.test.cryptall.com' type='chat'>
    <body>
        <msgid>a8aa6f8f-f162-4f1f-b9a0-834180c26fe0</msgid>      
        <sessionkey></sessionkey>      
        <creationtime>1432204640009</creationtime>      
        <senttime>1432204640009</senttime>
        <msgtype>9001</msgtype>      
        <body>4A8E47665F91C415B2E732E105E1FA68E01AF2EA9D03AE8374343A68683</body>      
        <thread>yyMz65</thread>
    </body>
</message>
```